# Do oven door liners commonly need replacing?

Tags: equipment, oven

The first time I used the "self clean" setting on this oven, the strip of padding around the oven door ... puffed out?  Heat leaks out ever since, even to the point where the oven light will sometimes pop on with the door closed.  I bought an oven thermometer, and if I wedge the door closed with a drawer, it seems to hold the correct temperature.

Is it simple & common to replace that liner? Or am I overreacting and there's nothing really wrong with the drawer method?  I'll admit, it IS handy to be able to blame the gimpy oven door any time a baking project doesn't turn out quite right.  ;)

Comment: That sure doesn't *sound* normal to me, especially if it happened the very first time.  Is it still under warranty?

Comment: Definitely doesn't sound normal. I'd contact the manufacturer.

Comment: Sadly, this was a few years ago.  Until my back went out, I think we used the oven 2-6 times per year, tops, and never really understood why we had to keep things in the oven so long...  wups!

Comment: For quite a while, I used a bungee cord to hold the oven door shut in a crappy apartment. It stayed out of the way and never caught fire, but I wasn't terribly happy about it either...

Answer (score 4):

I have never known anyone to replace them. Not me, not my mother (who used hers every other day almost). So no, that does not seem to be a normal thing. Contact the store!

Answer (score 4):

The strip is called a 'gasket' or sometimes an 'oven door seal', and you *can* get replacements (even online), [if you're willing to make the repair yourself](http://home.howstuffworks.com/how-to-repair-an-oven2.htm).

I don't know how difficult it'd be, it likely depends on the manufacturer and model.

I'd personally not recommend wedging the door shut ... that just seems like a potential hazard to me ... even if it's just someone walking through the kitchen and running into it.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll get hold of the manufacturer. Maybe they'll feel bad about it, if it's not a common problem & simple repair.